# i need to redirect all page except for 1 page with POST data

Tags: php, json, redirect

I need to redirect requests to my old domain to a new domain while retaining a page in the old domain.

- page.json with post data and will process on the old domain
- data.json with post data and need to be redirect to new domain
- stat.json with post data and need to be redirect to new domain... and continues

Edit: In short all .json with post data get redirect to new domain except for 1 page

How can i get it done, if possible at all?
I use fiddler to debug in raw view

Before redirect (with .htaccess method)

```
POST http://old.com/data.json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; GT-N7105 Build/JZO54K)
Host: old.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 100

session=gVgr30Erxf03cDaA&store_version=9203b&inventory_version=123
```

After redirect

```
GET http://new.com/data.json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; GT-N7105 Build/JZO54K)
Host: new.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `.htaccess` with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page\.json$  -                        [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^(.*\.json)$  http://newdomain.com/$1  [R=307,QSA]
```

- The 2nd line says: Don't change if the page matches 'page.json' and stop rewriting `[L]`.
- The 3th line says: Only do rewrite POST requests
- The 4th line says: Math anything that ends on '.json' and to a [temporary redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_307#3xx_Redirection) `[R=307]` to http://newdomain.com/{page}. Also add any URL parameters `[QSA]`.

---

### Proof of concept

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^$  http://test.jasny.net/redirect/posthere.php  [R=307,QSA]
```

index.html

```
<form action="/redirect/" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

posthere.php

```
<?
  var_dump($_POST);
```

### [See it work](http://test.jasny.net/redirect/)

Comment: ^page\.json$ the "\" must be in there too?

Comment: Alittle debug
POST olddomain.com/page.json HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; GT-N7105 Build/JZO54K) Host: olddomain.com Connection: Keep-Alive Accept-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 100 session=gVgr30ExUlMRSrxf03cDaA&store_version=82561f623cb74a0a309a0f92ef89203b&in‌​ventory_version=45c29fa6aabab80aa832d0752fcaee99

Comment: A `.` matches any character. The `\.` matches a dot.

Comment: A [307 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) doesn't turn POST requests into GET. I do know IE7/IE8 aren't doing that properly. You could try a [301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) instead.

Comment: i know it work but i still have no idea why it does not work for my application. I need to redirect everything even when it does not have post data so i did removed the rewritecond do u have a php where it will get the values and then insert to the new link? thanks for the help much appreciated =D

Answer (score 0):

i agree with arnold, .htaccess, but if u want ONLY requests with $_POST data then i would create a small php file that handle request, test if if it contain post then redirect to ur old domain, if not redirect to new domain

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^foo/bar$ http%1://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or redirect all traffic to php file and do:

```
if( count( $_POST ) < 1 ) {
    header( "HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    header( "Status: 301" );
    header( "Location: http://".CLIENT_DOMAIN."{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");     
    die();//or exit;
}else{////same}
```

Comment: You can also check that the request is a POST with mod_rewrite. I've added it to my answer. Using a PHP script works, but isn't needed.

Comment: i tested arnold, it does redirect(like with other method that i googled), but the post get lost somehow....
I cant script php. Unless someone is kind enough to help.

Comment: sorry i am a noob, i didnt get the part where if on page.json , no redirect